# Modern search in modern sites - retrieve choice field?

Tags: search, modern-team-site

I have added a choice field (multiple choices) to the page library of a modern site (communication site). I plan to write topics of the pages. I would like this to be a searchable item in the modern search (or even in the classic search for the matter) but the pages (News posts) do not show up.

What do I need to do to make this column searchable? will it change something if I do it with a metadata term set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the new crawled properties will appear in Search Schema, after this there should be Managed properties too, make sure, they are set as 'Searchable'.

Comment: what if after 1 hour still does not happen? if the word appears on the page under the form of the webpart Page details I do not understand why the search doesn't treat it as a word and search it anyway. I made the webparts searchable too

Comment: Not Web-Parts but the Managed Properties in Search Schema make Searchable